# How to Get Back the External SD Card Notification

Tags: notifications, external-sd

I used to have a notification whenever the external SD card was in the tablet. Recently that notification has disappeared. How can I get this notification back.

I like this notification since I am able to eject the card from it without needing to go thru the settings menu to get to it.

What is interesting is that when I insert a different card the notification is back. I only am missing it for the original card. Last time I had this problem I factory reset my tablet. I would rather not have to do this again.

I searched for a solution but only found solutions to get rid of the notification, not the opposite. I tried to reboot my device but that didn't help.

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Another great solution**, but your device must be rooted to be able to use this option (ASFAIK).

Use the sm tool
`sm forget [UUID | all]`
This makes the device forget the storage device with the given UUID or if you do all it forgets all the devices.

If your using Termux terminal emulator (as I am) you need to do `tsu -p` in order to be able to use the `sm` tool. If not you get an error. Basically what you need is for the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to point first to the android library path and `-p` prepends those paths **BEFORE** the termux library path.

I didn't try this in any other shell or terminal, but I'm assuming it should work there as well.

Answer (score 1):

Change the volume serial number of the sd card.

There might be various ways to do it, this one worked for me when I had the same problem after touching "clear all" when displaying notifications.

Mount the SD card on a windows PC.

Note the drive letter of the sd card by opening a windows explorer window.
For example let's say it was mounted as E:

In a command prompt window type the following command to find out the current volume id of the sd card, assuming the SD card is E: drive.

```
vol E:
```

It should give you a number like 1234-5678

Download the Microsoft utility "volumeid" from this [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/volumeid) at Microsoft:

Follow the instructions at the link for using the utility and give the SD card a new volume id.

Make sure you use the right drive letter, the drive letter of the SD card. You don't want to change your hard disk by mistake.

In a command prompt window, the syntax is:

```
volumeid E: 1234-5679
```

This will change the volume id of E: drive to 1234-5679

When you put the SD card back in you android device the device will think it's a different card and show the sd card mounted notification.

Comment: Great answer. Is there any way to do this in Linux? I don't always have access to a windows PC.

Answer (score 0):

To add to @Morris's answer a way to do it in Linux (or on the Android device itself using Termux)

Run `sudo blkid` to find which device is the sd card. (On my device it was `/dev/block/mmcblk1p1`)

Now run `sudo mlabel -i REPLACE-WITH-YOUR-SD-CARD-DEVICE -n` (`-n` generates a random Serial Number you can use `-N xxxxxxxx` where you replace the x's with hex digits for the serial number you want see the man pages for `mlabel`).

The idea of using `blkid` and `mlabel` I took form [Here! See JonathanS answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/196899/finding-a-unique-identifier-for-sd-cards). and the exact way of writing the `mlabel` command to use the undocumented `-i` option I took from [Here!](http://mclements.net/blogWP/index.php/2016/11/29/vfat-uuid-sd-cards-android-mount/)

[I ran these commands on the tablet using termux and instead of `sudo` I ran it as superuser doing `tsu -p` and then eliminating the `sudo` part of the commands.  I also needed to downgrade my `libandroid-support.so` library for it to work. I found that just doing `tsudo` (termux's version of `sudo`) gave me a large number of devices when I ran `blkid` and it was hard to figure out which one was the sd card.]